# Letsencrypt virtual host vs htaccess on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a site that I was working to move to use the virtualhost configuration over an .htaccess. Figuring if I have the access I should.

The rewrite I have was for php slim framework to remove index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I made the changes of moving from .htaccess to the production server routes were failing. I realized that the rewrites were not being followed on the :80 virtualhost but rather what was specified in the :443 letsencrpyt virtualhost.

In a pinch I just moved the above re-write into the letsencrpyt and voila working.

It seems that certbot uses the :80 port to create the :443 so I cannot remove that and just go with the generated one. Right now I am just duplicating the logic between the two.

Question I have at this point for this type of re-write should I just leave it in the .htaccess? Or is there a way to update the ssl vhost with certbot when I make changes to the default port 80 one?

Comment: The whole point of using a encryption certificate (be it letsencrypt or any other alternative) is to be able to use the `https` protocol, so port 443. You do not want to go on to use `http`, so port 80, you want to deactivate that.

Comment: @arkascha I understand that 443 is ssl. It seems that certbot uses what is in 80 though to build the 443 vhost. Hence my dilemma.

Comment: So? Why is that a problem? The script setting up the certificates does not care for paths, it actually starts a separate http server that has nothing to do with the one normally operated. Rewriting does not take place and is not required at that time.

Comment: @arkascha My concern is not about the 443. Right now I am duplicating logic in the http and https vhosts. Since certbot uses the http to build the https I am wondering if it is better to just leave this in the htaccess or if there is a way to manage it in the vhost conf files.

Comment: I posted an answer to that specific question. But I still fail to understand why you think you have to configure such rules in the http host at all. Anyway, have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your comments to the question I now see that your actual question is:

"How is it possible to share configuration directives between different hosts in an apache http server? "

This is easily possible using the `Include` statement:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # include the rules common for http and https
        Include sites-includes/shared-config.inc
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # include the rules common for http and https
        Include sites-includes/shared-config.inc
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Using that you can now define common configuration directives in the file `sites-includes/shared-config.inc` (or wherever you want to place it).

Comment: The issue I was facing was that I was using certbot to generate the ssl vhost and it does that by creating another file. This answer actually made me realize that I do not need certbot to generate it for me. I can do that myself.